# How to realize System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Like

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, lambda

I am writing a dynamic linq query to realize paging, and I am now facing a problem, I need the `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Like` function, but it does not exist in `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`, here is my code.

```
Expression mWhereFunc;          // Filter clause 
ParameterExpression mLinqParam; // Linq param

// Get current request page
string mCurPage = this.Request.QueryString["page"];
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(mCurPage))
{
    mCurPage = "1";
}

mLinqParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ORD_Order), "p");
mWhereFunc = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(mLinqParam,
     typeof(ORD_Order).GetProperty("ItemIsValid")), 
     Expression.Constant(true));

string mOrderSN = this.Request.QueryString["txtOrderSN"];
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(mOrderSN))
{
    mWhereFunc = Expression.And(mWhereFunc, 
     **Expression.Equal**(Expression.Property(mLinqParam,
     typeof(ORD_Order).GetProperty("OrderSN")), 
     Expression.Constant(mOrderSN)));
}

var mLambdaWhere = (Expression<Func<ORD_Order, 
      bool>>)Expression.Lambda<Func<ORD_Order, bool>>(mWhereFunc, 
     new ParameterExpression[] { mLinqParam });
Func<ORD_Order, Int32> mLambdaOrder = p => p.OrderID;

IORD_OrderRepository rptOrder = new ORD_OrderRepository();
ICTM_CustomerRepository rptCtm = new CTM_CustomerRepository();

var list = from o in rptOrder.GetAll()
             .Where(mLambdaWhere)
                 .OrderBy(mLambdaOrder)
                 .Skip((int.Parse(mCurPage) - 1) * mPageSize).Take(mPageSize)
               join c in rptCtm.GetAll()
               on o.CustomerID equals c.CustomerID
               select new
               {
                   o.OrderID,
                   o.OrderSN,
                   o.CustomerID,
                   c.ContactName,
                   o.Status,
                   o.CreateDate,
                   o.Description
               };
```

**Expression.Equal** is the place where I want to change it to Expression.Like
[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I modified my code like this

```
mWhereFunc = Expression.And(mWhereFunc, Expression.Call(
   Expression.Property(mLinqParam, typeof(ORD_Order).GetProperty("OrderSN")), 
   typeof(String).GetMethod("Contains"), 
   new Expression[] { Expression.Constant(mOrderSN) }));
```

and it works, many thanks to all of you.

Comment: Thank you Steven!  Your short answer advanced my knowlege alot!

Answer (score 1):

Like equivalents for linq are `String.Contains`, `String.StartsWith`  etc. http://www.simonrhart.com/2008/06/using-like-in-linq-to-sql-under-c.html

Answer (score 0):

if you are using NHibernate you can create a Like method and use a Expression to call that

You can check this post on how to do the "Like" extension here: [NHibernate Linq Provider Extension](http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.mx/2010/07/nhibernate-linq-provider-extension.html)

And then you build the "Like" Expression like this:

```
Expression.Call(typeof(MyLinqExtensions).GetMethod("IsLike"), Expression.Property(mLinqParam,
     typeof(ORD_Order).GetProperty("OrderSN")), 
     Expression.Constant(mOrderSN)));
```

**EDIT:** Just as an additional comment, you should use `Expression.AndAlso` instead of `Expression.And` since the first one is the && operator and the last one is the & operator

**EDIT 2:** For Entity Framework check this post (Linq To Entities scenario): [SQL User-Defined Functions in Entity Framework 4](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2009/05/28/entity-sql-user-defined-functions-in-entity-framework-4.aspx), I have no experience with it but it seems the same as a NH provider, after doing that then building the Linq Expression should be the same i posted before

Comment: I am using entity framework 4, is there any way to solve this problem?